# The wrong Microsoft Translator web address appears in Internet history

Tags: browser

I have noticed in my Internet history an entry for Microsoft Translate - microsofttranslator.com - but the link is broken. Why has this appeared? Is it linked to a page which has a language it is trying to translate? I haven't deliberately used this page.

Comment: Probably an URL that MS uses to translate pages. The link is *not* broken, it redirects to http://www.bing.com/translator/

Comment: I've intentionally applied a vague tag (to replace the bad "[microsoft](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again)" one) because the poster didn't specify what browser is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of it. Probably a rogue website in the past (brought down by authorities long before today).

I suggest you to delete the link and run some virus/malware scans to ensure your computer is clean.

**PS:** Microsoft's translation service is called [Bing Translator](http://www.bing.com/translator).